# How to define coordinate system and geographic transformation for a CAD drawing?

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, autocad, cad

I am a GIS guy and I occasionally work with CAD files as well. Now I need to know how I can define a coordinate system and a geographic transformation for a CAD Drawing. According to ESRI:

*"You can define a coordinate system and a geographic transformation and create and edit metadata for CAD datasets. The information is stored in external support files and moves with the CAD dataset when it is managed in the Catalog window."*

But don't know how to do this! Can you please let me know or point me to a tutorial to understand this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29386/trouble-when-georeferencing-cad-files-in-arcmap/29396#29396](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29386/trouble-when-georeferencing-cad-files-in-arcmap/29396#29396)

Comment: Hi Arabella, thanks for reply but this is actually not an answer to my question.What I am Asking is For Examle I have vertices coordinates of a claim(Polygon) in UTM Zone 10 Nad 83.Now I would like to draw the claim as actual size and position on the world on CAD drawing. Is this possible or not?

Comment: I have to agree with @Arabella - it sounds like you need to georeference a CAD file for which there is also [**Online Help**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001000000010000000) available.

Comment: possible information here: http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/ps/dl/item?siteID=123112&id=18738873&linkID=9240697